# Get derived class via dynamic Assembly loading?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have 2 dlls, one with an interface and another that actually uses the interface.
I can call the 2nd dll using reflection, but I wanted to know if I can get more information about it using the interface.

I have something like...

```
// the interface dll
namespace Mynamespace{
  public interface Interface1
  {
    int Add( int a, int b);
  }
}
```

and another interface in the same dll...
note that it is derived from the first one.

```
namespace Mynamespace{
  public interface Interface2 : Interface1
  {
    int Sub( int a, int b);
  }
}
```

I then call a method using reflection

```
// get the 2 interfaces
var asm = Assembly.LoadFile( dllInterfacePath);
var type1 = asm.GetType("Mynamespace.Interface1");
var type2 = asm.GetType("Mynamespace.Interface2");

// get the main class
var asmDll = Assembly.LoadFile( dllPath);
var type = asmDll.GetType("MyMS.SomeClass");

// create an instance
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance( type, null );
```

Now my question is how can I tell if the instance created is derived off `Interface2` or `Interface1`, I could look for method "Sub(...)" and if it is not present then I know it is of type `Interface1`.

But I was wondering if there was a better function to dynamically achieve this?

I cannot use

```
typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyMS.SomeClass));
```

as both `Interface1` and `MyMS.SomeClass` are dynamically loaded and not referenced in the project.

Comment: @wiktor-zychla, I have edited it to clarify why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: You don't have to use the `typeof` to have a type reference. The api works well for dynamically loaded types, too.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work. ``typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyMS.SomeClass));`` or ``type.IsAssignableFrom(type1);`` does not work

Comment: It does work, take a look at my detailed answer.

Comment: Can't you just say: `type1.IsAssignableFrom(type)` ?

Comment: No, as per my comment, it does not work. (see the accepted answer for the reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use the `typeof` to have a type reference, the reflection API works well for dynamically loaded types, too.

> Sorry, but it does not work. typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyMS.SomeClass)); or type.IsAssignableFrom(type1); does not work

It does work but by calling `LoadFile` you are basically loading the same interface assembly twice, thus making it impossible to refer to the same interface type on the class that implements it:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom/

Just replace `LoadFile` with `LoadFrom` or even `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`:

I just recreated your scenario, I have an assembly with the interface and another assembly with the implementation.

```
Assembly interfaceLib      = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom( "InterfaceLib.dll" );
Assembly implementationLib = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom( "ImplementationLib.dll" );

var i = interfaceLib.GetType( "InterfaceLib.Interface1" );
var t = implementationLib.GetType( "ImplementationLib.Class1" );

var b = i.IsAssignableFrom( t );

Console.WriteLine( b );

// prints "true"
```

If I switch to `LoadFile` I get `false`.

Comment: The ``LoadFile`` vs ``LoadFrom`` was the issue, the subtle, (yet important), difference between the two is not immediately obvious if you are not looking for it.